# How to improve the performance of processing multiple Arraylist request in a synchronized way to create them into a final list with no duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a scenario in which I have a method who gets results as an Arraylist in a form like as shown in the below picture.

[image]

So, as a brief explanation to the picture, I will get **Result 1** as the first chunk of objects, then I will be getting **Result 2** which actually contains **Result 1** and a new set of objects, and this goes on.

Note: All these chunk of objects will contain duplicates. So I will have to filter this out.

My aim is to create one single list out of these chunks without having any duplicates and have only one object from a family(one special character of these objects).

Please find the current code snippet, used in the synchronized method I call whenever I get a chunk of result, which I am using to implement this:

On every result update, this method will be called with the result arrayList.

```
private synchronized void processRequestResult(QueryResult result)
{        
        ArrayList currArrayList = result.getResultsList();
        ArrayList tempArrayList = result.getResultsList();

        /**
         * Remove all elements in prevArrayList from currArrayList
         * 
         * As per the javadocs, this would take each record of currArrayList and compare with each record of prevArrayList, 
         * and if it finds both equal, it will remove the record from currArrayList
         * 
         * The problem is that its easily of n square complexity.
         */
        currArrayList.removeAll(prevArrayList);

        // Clone and keep the currList for dealing with next List 
        prevArrayList = (ArrayList) tempArrayList.clone();


        for (int i = 0; i < currArrayList.size(); i++)
        {
            Object resultObject = currArrayList.get(i);

            // Check for if it reached the max of items to be displayed in the list.
            if (hashMap.size() >= MAX_RESULT_LIMIT)
            {
                //Stop my requests
                //Launch Message
                break;
            }

            //To check if of the same family or duplicate
            if (resultObject instanceof X)
            {
                final Integer key = Integer.valueOf(resultObject.familyID);
                hashMap.put(key, (X)myObject);
            }
            else if (resultObject instanceof Y)
            {
                final Integer key = Integer.valueOf(resultObject.familyID);
                hashMap.put(key, (Y)myObject);
            }
        }

        // Convert the HashSet to arrayList
        allResultsList = new ArrayList(hashMap.values());

        //Update the change to screen
}
```

In theory, I should only try to parse the delta object in the result which I receive next. So I went for removeAll method of an arrayList and then check for duplicates and same family by using a hashMap.

Please see my inline comments in the code, because of that, I would like to get some pointers to improve my performance to this process.

---

**Update**:

The special character of these object are that, a set of objects can belong to the same family(an ID), So only one object from each family should be present in the Final List.

SO that was the reason why I used a hashMap and made the familyID as the key.

Comment: Is this just eliminating duplicates from a series of lists to make one list? Is preserving order important?

Comment: If I understand correctly, preserving order is not necessary.

Comment: "A single list without duplicates", tried gauging performance of dumping it all into a hashset? I suspect better than N^2

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the diagram, or the code

Comment: @Bohemian: The relevance of the diagram is to show that the succeeding result list will contain all the elements in some order of the previous received result list. The delta is the only change between the two adjacent result lists. There can be duplicates in the delta list as well. Please explain which part you dint understand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the diagram or the code, but I'm assuming the requirement is to create a List of elements that are unique.

Firstly, a Set is really what you need:

```
Set<MyClass> set = new HashSet<MyClass>();
```

Every time you get a new list of results:

```
set.addAll(list);
```

If you *really* need a List:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>(set);
```

Comment: I have updated my question with one more detail about the objects. That was the reason why I went for a HashMap and couldn't actually use a HashSet, as I don't think we can override the equals of a hashSet.